# can't seen in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine

I create a yaml file to create rabbitmq kubernetes cluster. I can see pods. But when I write kubectl get deployment. I cant see there. I can't access to rabbitmq ui page.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbit
  name: rabbit
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    name: mqtt
  - port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    name: ui
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbit
spec:
  serviceName: rabbit
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbit
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbit
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq
      nodeSelector:
        rabbitmq: "clustered"
```

Comment: May I suggest you deploy using a helm chart instead if you intend to use. It provides a much more robust setup than what you have above. . You will have to learn about  helm first and set it up before it will work https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/. Once setup you simply run `helm install my-release stable/rabbitmq` and that's it.

Comment: +1 for using helm to install rabbitmq, steps are in https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq.

Answer (score 2):

@arghya-sadhu's answer is correct.

**NB** I'm unfamiliar with RabbitMQ but you may need to use a different image (see ['Management Plugin`](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq)) to include the UI.

See below for more details.

You should be able to hack your way to the UI on one (!) of the Pods via:

```sh
PORT=8888
kubectl port-forward pod/rabbit-0 --namespace=${NAMESPACE} ${PORT}:15672
```

And then browse `localhost:${PORT}` (if `8888` is unavailable, try another).

I **suspect** (!) this won't work unless you use the image with the management plugin.

#### Plus

- The `Service` needs to select the `StatefulSet`'s Pods

Within the Service `spec` you should add perhaps:

```
selector:
  app: rabbit
```

- Presumably (!?) you are using a private repo (because you have `imagePullSecrets`).

If you don't and wish to use DockerHub, you may remove the `imagePullSecrets` section.

- It's useful to document (!) container ports albeit not mandatory:

In the `StatefulSet`

```
ports:
- containerPort: 5672
- containerPort: 15672
```

#### Debug

```sh
NAMESPACE="default" # Or ...
```

Ensure the StatefulSet is created:

```sh
kubectl get statesfulset/rabbit --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Check the Pods:

```sh
kubectl get pods --selector=app=rabbit --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

You can check the the Pods are bound to a (!) Service:

```sh
kubectl describe endpoints/rabbit --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

**NB** You should see 3 addresses (one per Pod)

Get the NodePort either:

```sh
kubectl get service/rabbit --namespace=${NAMESPACE} --output=json
kubectl describe service/rabbit --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

You will **need** to use the NodePort to access both the MQTT endpoint and the UI.

Comment: where I should add DEBUG to .yml file

Comment: The Debug section describes some `kubectl` commands that you can try after you've `kubectl apply --filename=...` the spec to your cluster.

Comment: when I write this deployment it works but when I made it StatefulSet. Have you any idea about this problem?

Comment: "it works" means that you're able to access the UI? I'll try deploying it as a Deployment. It worked for me as a StatefulSet in that I could see the Pods deployed but I was unable to access the HTTP UI on 15672 and didn't have an MQTT client to test it on 5672.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Your issues is that StatefulSets and NodePorts are *incongruous*. StatefulSets are designed to create uniquely identifiable Pods because -- per the name -- the intent is that each Pod has some unique state making it unique. The NodePort attempts to load balance across cloned (not unique but cloned) Pods. When using StatesfulSets, you'll need a mechanism to explicitly reference a specific Pod. That explains why Deployment works because the NodePort picks one Pod at random **assuming** that all Pods are clones.

Answer (score 1):

[statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) are different kubernetes resources. You have created statefulsets. That's why you don't see deployments. If you do

`kubectl get statefulset` you should see it and also both statefulset and deployment creates pod finally so you should be able to see rabbitmq pods if you do `kubectl get pods`

Since you have created a Nodeport service. You should be able to access it via `http://nodeip:nodeport` where `nodeip` is ip of any worker node in your kubernetes cluster.

You can get to know what is the Nodeport(a number between 30000-32767) by

```
kubectl describe services rabbit
```

Here is the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) on accessing a [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service from outside the cluster.

Comment: But I cant login to rabbitm ui page. and I dont know what is wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access it from outside the cluster ? what error you get ?can you access it from inside the cluster like curl to it from another pod?

Comment: I cant acces to IP:PORT IP and Port are 100% correct but I cant access to see UI rabbit page